# How to remove potential corporate spies from a list of "VIP customers" attending a company event?

Tags: professionalism, clients, events

I am in a mass consumer business so anyone could be a consumer, however we sometimes invite random winners from a draw to VIP events near/at the company premise.

I noticed that one of the "winners" is someone whom I clearly know to be a competitor (an owner of a competitor company). I have the authority to decide who to include or exclude from the list, but I was wondering if there might be a "most professional behavior" in a situation like this.
Especially I fear that if I do remove them (after they received the automated invitation) they might retaliate somehow...

How to remove them, or at least how to ensure this doesn't cause a conflict of interest professionally?

Is it appropriate for me to use my knowledge of competitors and their people to make decisions in my workplace?

Comment: Your question has insufficient information. What is "the VIP event near/at the company premise"? Why would it be a problem if the competitor is there?

Comment: I updated the question in an attempt to bring it on topic.

Comment: "spy" is a pretty strong word.  When we do this, we prefer to call it "market research"

Answer (score 9):

You have this authority for precisely this reason. You know people in the industry and you know what's going on. That's partly why you have your job.  Go ahead and exclude this competitor from your event.

If you don't have to revoke an invitation you already made, just don't send the invitation.  If you do have to revoke the invitation, just write a note staying something like "hey, nice try, but we can't include you in this event. I'm sure you understand." Be polite but firm.

And your people should be trying to infiltrate their events too.  That's part of what honest competition is about.

Finally: automated selection of guests? Really? This is a sales event. Invite the people most likely to have their chance of buying something increased.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel you must exclude them; why try to win them over by inviting them separately to your premises at a time and place that is appropriately "sanitized"?

You will score a win (and your competitor will know it, believe me) by giving them special attention; plus you don't risk unintended disclosure.

Regarding your other question - it is absolutely okay to make decisions at your work with knowledge of your competitors - it goes on every, single day and I would dare to say in every single business.

Just look at Samsung v. Apple or other similar cases.

You have to be mindful that the information you are using was not obtained in any questionable manner or means; because this may land not only you but your employer in some serious trouble.